# Show that there exists a constant a such that $f = ag$ where $f,g$ are linear applications from $W$ to $V*$ (vector spaces)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, bilinear-form, dual-spaces

So, I couldn't insert everything in my title, but I'm currently struggling with this linear algebra exercise, and I need your help:

Let $V, W$ be vector spaces over a field $K$ and let $V^*$ be the dual of V. Let $f,g:W \rightarrow V^*$ be injective linear applications. Show that if $Ker(f(x)) = Ker(g(x))$ then there exists a constant a in $K$ such that $f=ag$

Comment: Please give us some context for your question. What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Also, if $f,g$ are injective, then it's clear that $\ker f$  and $\ker g$ are both zero, which means that they have the same kernel (regardless of whether $f = ag$). So, it seems as though you're missing or have incorrectly written a piece of the question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ker(f(x)) is the Kernel of the function of the dual space, not the ker of f itself.

Comment: If that's the case, then is the statement that $\ker(f(x)) = \ker(g(x))$ for all $x \in W$, or simply that there exists an $x \in W$ for which $\ker f(x) = \ker g(x)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're right that should be specified, it's true for all x in W. Sorry.

Comment: That's fine. Could you also answer the first question? On this site, users are expect to post questions that include [more than just the problem statement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/81360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that for $\gamma,\delta \in V^*$, if $\ker \gamma = \ker \delta$, then there exists an $a$ for which $\gamma = a \delta$.

Then, show that if there exist vectors $x_1,x_2 \in V$ for which $f(x_1) = a_1 g(x_1)$ and $f(x_2) = a_2 g(x_2)$ with $a_1 \neq a_2$, then there exists an $x \in V$ for which $g(x)$ fails to be a multiple of $f(x)$.